# GCC to LLVM migration tips?

Tags: macos, gcc, llvm, xcode4

Xcode 4 comes with LLVM. As a casual programmer (i.e. download some open source projects and compile them on a mac via command line), is there any tips for the transition?

Comment: Build the Linux Kernel with it and check out if it really runs faster.

Comment: Koning: May I assume you're joking?  Building Linux with clang is one of the [longer term goals](http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=4068).  That is - you can't yet build Linux with clang.

Answer (score 2):

Compile something and see what doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

As a casual programmer, I've found that "it just works".

If there are esoteric places where it breaks, you are not very likely to run across them.